# Send and sendmany API

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I have 10 bitcoin transactions.

I use the following ways.

1) Send 10 times of 1 transaction with send API.

2) Send 1 times of 10 transactions with sendMany API.

Obviously 2nd way save fee

but is that good if I always use sendMany API always even though I have only 1 transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you actually have 10 addresses you want to send to because you know the `sendmany` saves fees. Using 2) is always preferable, it's essentially what people complain about when fees are too high, often called Transaction Batching, there's nothing wrong with it.

If you're looking for more information on Tx batching [look here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Techniques_to_reduce_transaction_fees#Payment_batching)